# Cannot start worker through SSHCluster while dask-ssh works properly

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Whenever attempting to start a cluster via SSHCluster, the scheduler would start but the worker would not with no clear indication why in the error stack:

```
from distributed import SSHCluster

cluster = SSHCluster(
 ["10.244.14.111", "10.244.14.112"],
 connect_options={"known_hosts": None},
 worker_options={"nthreads": 2},
 scheduler_options={"port": 8796, "dashboard_address": ":8797"}
)
```

returns:

```
(mre_env) #[mxs05@auggsmx030:/home/mxs05]# python test.py
distributed.deploy.ssh - INFO - Warning: Your terminal does not set locales.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    scheduler_options={"port": 8796, "dashboard_address": ":8797"}
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/ssh.py", line 371, in SSHCluster
    return SpecCluster(workers, scheduler, name="SSHCluster", **kwargs)
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 281, in __init__
    self.sync(self._start)
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/cluster.py", line 189, in sync
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 351, in sync
    raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 334, in f
    result[0] = yield future
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 309, in _start
    self.scheduler = await self.scheduler
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/spec.py", line 71, in _
    await self.start()
  File "/xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/ssh.py", line 210, in start
    raise Exception("Worker failed to start")
Exception: Worker failed to start
```

At the same time, I can start a cluster without issue through dask-ssh:

```
dask-ssh 10.244.14.111 10.244.14.112

---------------------------------------------------------------
                 Dask.distributed v2021.03.0

Worker nodes: 2
  0: 10.244.14.111
  1: 10.244.14.112

scheduler node: 10.244.14.111:8786
---------------------------------------------------------------


[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/bin/python -m distributed.cli.dask_scheduler --port 8786
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/bin/python -m distributed.cli.dask_worker 10.244.14.111:8786 --nthreads 0 --host 10.244.14.111 --memory-limit auto
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/bin/python -m distributed.cli.dask_worker 10.244.14.111:8786 --nthreads 0 --host 10.244.14.112 --memory-limit auto
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:120: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] :   warnings.warn(msg)
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://10.244.14.111:34611'
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory '/home/mxs05/dask-worker-space/worker-iylgpom1', purging
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.nanny - INFO -         Start Nanny at: 'tcp://10.244.14.112:37080'
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.diskutils - INFO - Found stale lock file and directory '/home/mxs05/dask-worker-space/worker-smm8q6xg', purging
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.http.proxy - INFO - To route to workers diagnostics web server please install jupyter-server-proxy: python -m pip install jupyter-server-proxy
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - -----------------------------------------------
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Clear task state
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:  tcp://10.244.14.111:8786
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO -   dashboard at:                     :8787
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register worker <Worker 'tcp://10.244.14.111:36467', name: tcp://10.244.14.111:36467, memory: 0, processing: 0>
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://10.244.14.111:36467
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:120: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] :   warnings.warn(msg)
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:  tcp://10.244.14.111:36467
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:  tcp://10.244.14.111:36467
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -          dashboard at:        10.244.14.111:36843
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.244.14.111:8786
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                        144
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                  812.94 GB
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/mxs05/dask-worker-space/worker-eefsc3yq
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to:   tcp://10.244.14.111:8786
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.111 ] : distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : /xxx/shared/mx/python/mre_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:120: UserWarning: Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] :   warnings.warn(msg)
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Register worker <Worker 'tcp://10.244.14.112:36828', name: tcp://10.244.14.112:36828, memory: 0, processing: 0>
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.scheduler - INFO - Starting worker compute stream, tcp://10.244.14.112:36828
[ scheduler 10.244.14.111:8786 ] : distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -       Start worker at:  tcp://10.244.14.112:36828
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -          Listening to:  tcp://10.244.14.112:36828
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -          dashboard at:        10.244.14.112:35395
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - Waiting to connect to:   tcp://10.244.14.111:8786
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -               Threads:                        144
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -                Memory:                  812.94 GB
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -       Local Directory: /home/mxs05/dask-worker-space/worker-fa8dvpb7
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO -         Registered to:   tcp://10.244.14.111:8786
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.worker - INFO - -------------------------------------------------
[ worker 10.244.14.112 ] : distributed.core - INFO - Starting established connection
```

My guess is the difference in behaviour can be attributed to one using asyncssh and the other one using paramiko.

Any idea what the issue could be and how to retrieve more verbose logs?

Python 3.6.2
dask    2021.3.0
distributed 2021.3.0
asyncssh 2.5.0
paramiko 2.7.2